# Is it possible to expressly set a line's height of text underlined using `text-decoration: underline;` in CSS?

Tags: css, browser, text-decorations

Is it possible to expressly set a line's height of text underlined using `text-decoration: underline;` in CSS? IE and FireFox renders text with `font-weight: bold;` and `text-decoration: underline;` applied as a bolded or a fat line for lack of a better word. Chrome, Safari and Opera renders it as 1px.

The goal is to render it consistently across browsers (No, really? Go on!). Any suggestions?

Comment: Please can you rephrase you question, it doesn't seem very clear to me.

Comment: When you make text bold (using CSS) and the text is underlined (using CSS), the line underneath the text renders as bold too (thick line) in IE and FireFox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easiest thing would be wrap it with an `<b>` element and give it a `bottom-border:1px solid;`

that would make sure that the udnerline is 1 px in all browsers

Comment: That wouldn't work when the text stretches more than line. However, I guess you rarely want that with underlined text anyway.

Comment: +1, that works for FireFox. I'm still getting the bolded line in IE using your method. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Mr. Smith: If it still doesn't work, wrap the entire thing (including the `<b>` element) in another `<span>` tag, and apply the `bottom-border: 1px solid;` to that. It's not very pretty though...

Comment: It still doesn't work in IE, but I have to say, it's IE 9 beta. Maybe they'll fix it. Marked as answer, thanks for your help Herman.